# Java fill variable from threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any possible way to populate a List or any other data from multiple threads?

I have already tried to use a synchronized list.

```
public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<String> list = 
         Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRunnable r = new MyRunnable();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r);
        t1.start();
        for(String s : list)
             System.out.println(s);
    }
}
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     @Override 
     public void run() { 
         Main.list.add("testing some code");
     } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a possible way. One of the possible ways is to use a synchronized list. What's your problem exactly?

Comment: The synchronized list is inside the Main class. After running the threads and filling the data ( with some strings ) the list is still empty when accessed from the Main class

Comment: Please show us the code.

Comment: @IoanMihaila that's not because of synchronization, that's because you did something else wrong

Comment: Ioan, never put code into comments. You can edit your Q.

Answer (score 3):

You have a race condition. The main program prints the list while it is still empty. Only then will the thread work and add something to it.

Wait for the thread to complete:

```
t1.join();
// now print
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use collections from `java.util.concurrent` package when working with threads. They are more preferable to synchronized collections, because they provide additional atomic methods, like `putIfAbsent` for map.

But this is only theory, could you put some code?

Update:
Your problem comes from completing main thread before your `MyRunnable` finishes. You need to add

```
t1.join()
```

This will tell your Main class to wait untill `MyRunnable` thread finishes.

Comment: You don't *need* to. Synchronized collections do work (although they don't have the fancy atomic operations).

Comment: Thank you for confirming me.

Comment: But the honor is yours on this answer:)